# Vim: make command result covers window

Tags: vim, makefile

I've got a problem with vim, so if there are any vim experts out there I'd be glad if someone could help me out.
I'm quite new to Vim so if I'm missing something obvious here I'm sorry for wasting your time.

So I started to use Vim a few days ago and now I learned about the `:make` command which runs my Makefile.
The problem I have is that the result of that command which is displayed looks incomplete and appears on a weird position on the screen. Also all my other stuff disappears until I press enter.

[image: Here is how it looks]

I learned that there is this quickfix window that I can open with `:copen` and it also displays the cmd command that my makefile executed.

[image: Copen window]

So why does it look so weird / covers my screen?
Is there a way to display it inside of the copen window?

I'd be happy if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: It would be better to share your `~/.vimrc` file and your makefile because sometimes the problem is there.

Comment: I've got a fresh vim install and my makefile is just compiling that one file. Apparently it was something temporary with the terminal or something, because now it doesn't look broken anymore. Still looking for a way to have a seperate tab for the terminal though.